# Converting time into 12 hour format without the AM/PM

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I would like to pull the datetime data from MSSQL 2014 displaying only the 12 hour format and WITHOUT the AM/PM. I have tried everything suggested over the internet as follows:

```
time_adm = convert(varchar(15), CAST(hadmlog.admdate AS TIME), 100), --//2:30PM
```

I also tried the `format()` but it returns an error "Common language runtime (CLR) execution is not supported under lightweight pooling ... etc"

```
time_adm22 = FORMAT(CAST(hadmlog.admdate AS DATETIME),'hh:mm') --error
```

Comment: Try this: `DECLARE @t varchar(7) = convert(varchar(15), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t)-2)`

Comment: In your case, it will be something like: `DECLARE @t varchar(7) = convert(varchar(15), CAST(hadmlog.admdate AS TIME), 100)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@t, 1, LEN(@t)-2)`

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES({ts'2017-01-01 07:13:52'}),({ts'2017-01-01 17:13:52'})

SELECT t.SomeDate
      ,a.FormattedTime
      ,LEFT(a.FormattedTime,PATINDEX('%[a,p]m',a.FormattedTime)-1) 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(t.SomeDate AS TIME),100) AS FormattedTime) AS a
```

The result

```
SomeDate                    FormattedTime   YourOutput
2017-01-01  07:13:52.000    7:13AM          7:13
2017-01-01  17:13:52.000    5:13PM          5:13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a string `Replace` to eliminate the AM and PM:

```
select hadmlog.admdate,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(convert(varchar(7), CAST(hadmlog.admdate AS Time) , 100),'AM',''),'PM','') as Converted
from hadmlog
```